# d3 color scale - linear with multiple colors?

Tags: colors, d3.js

I'm trying to create something a little like a quantize scale, but act like a linear color scale?

When I try to put multiple colors into a linear scale, it seems to only scale between the first two colors.

I'd like multiple colors like a quantize scale, but fade between those colors. I'm unsure if this is possible.

```
//red and green works ok
var color = d3.scale.linear()
            .range(['red','green']);

//doesn't work - only red and green show
var color = d3.scale.linear()
            .range(['red','green', 'blue']);


//red green and blue show, however it doesn't fade between the colors
var color = d3.scale.quantize()
            .range(['red','green', 'blue']);
```

Answer (score 36):

You have to use domain 'pivot' value like:

```
d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, pivot, max])
    .range(['red', 'green', 'blue']);
```

From the [documentation for continuous scale domains](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#continuous_domain):

> Although continuous scales typically have two values each in their domain and range, specifying more than two values produces a piecewise scale. For example, to create a diverging color scale that interpolates between white and red for negative values, and white and green for positive values, say:

```
var color = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([-1, 0, 1])
    .range(["red", "white", "green"]);

color(-0.5); // "rgb(255, 128, 128)"
color(+0.5); // "rgb(128, 192, 128)"
```

Comment: Thanks Anto, I'm in a different world now and haven't had a chance to give it a shot, but that sounds like a good idea +1 from me.

Comment: Your link has gone broken due to move of API docs as v.4 of D3 is up.

Comment: @KonradViltersten this is a great reason why people shouldn't post a link as an answer.

Comment: @JasTonAChair I agree with you on th eprinciple. However, **some** links are to be relied on (MSDN, jQuery API etc.) but **only and strictly** after very careful consideration. And even then, it's safest to provide the minimal self-sustaining content. Also, in my opinion, the rule should be "*the one who provided the link is the one responsible for maintaining its validity*".

Comment: edited to quote the relevant description and example from docs

Answer (score 0):

Anto's solution works great if you want to blend 3 colors. In my case, I needed a way to blend an arbitrary number of colors. For me, the trick was to set up the domain correctly. Take for example, the following array of colors:

```
var colors = ['#084594', '#2171b5', '#4292c6', '#6baed6', '#9ecae1', '#c6dbef', '#eff3ff'];
```

You can create a domain array with values from -1 to +1 like this:

```
    var domain = [-1];
    var increment = 2/(colors.length-1);
    for (var i=0; i<colors.length-2; i++){
        var previous = domain[domain.length-1];
        domain.push(previous+increment);
    }
    domain.push(1);
```

Once the domain array is created, you can create a color function like this:

```
    var getColor = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain(domain)
        .range(colors);
```

If you want to get color values at specific percentages (like chroma does), you can do something like this:

```
    var p = 0.25; //Valid range for p is 0.0-1.0
    var x = (p*2)-1;
    var color = d3.color(getColor(x));
    console.log(color.formatHex());
```