# D3: How to interpolate between two colors?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to create a color variable to give my scatterplot points color based on their value. Trying to make it range from 0 (red) to 1 (green) and scale linearly between the two.

I tried the suggestion in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27574034/create-dynamic-d3-color-scale-between-two-color-values), but it didn't work. I also tried the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22893789/d3-color-scale-linear-with-multiple-colors).

Try 1

```
var color = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain(0, .5, 1)
  .range(["red","white","green"]);

  console.log(color(+0))
  console.log(color(+.5))
  console.log(color(+1))
```

Output

```
rgb(255, 0, 0)
rgb(255, 0, 0)
rgb(255, 0, 0)
```

Try 2

```
  var color = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain(0, 1)
    .range(["red","green"]);

  console.log(color(+0))
  console.log(color(+.5))
  console.log(color(+1))
```

Output

```
rgb(0, 0, 0)
rgb(0, 0, 0)
rgb(0, 0, 0)
```

Try 3

```
  var color = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain(0, 1)
    .range(["#ff0000","#00ff00"]);

  console.log(color(+0))
  console.log(color(+.5))
  console.log(color(+1))
```

Output

```
rgb(0, 0, 0)
rgb(0, 0, 0)
rgb(0, 0, 0)
```

My desired output is

```
rgb(255, 0, 0)
rgb(128, 128,0)
rgb(0, 255, 0)
```

Comment: [Might try out the d3-interpolate package.](https://github.com/d3/d3-interpolate) It should contain everything you need, and is well documented. Also check out [this similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45857682/interpolation-of-colors)

Comment: This question was marked as a duplicate, but the dupe target was wrong: the problem here has nothing to do with the interpolation, it's just the domain: it has to be an **array**. So, in your try #1, do `.domain([0, .5, 1])` and you'll get the expected result. I already changed the dupe target to the correct one (out of many).